# C# Webservice disable message Validation

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

We are using a web service from a party who has made changes to it. Those changes cause some of the response messages to give an invalid validation error. The wise thing to do  i think is to update to the new specification of the web service but somehow they cant publish is. There solution is to disable the validation on our side so that all messages will pass. I have been searching to turn of this validation but cant find any answers. Is there a option in .Net that can make sure response messages don't get validated?

Comment: have you heard of versioning?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off message validation is probably not a good solution. Suggest you check out versioning:

- [Principles of Service Design: Service Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954726.aspx)
- [Best practices for Web services versioning](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-version/)
- [Strategies for updating or versioning web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931109/strategies-for-updating-or-versioning-web-services)

Comment: Hi Mitch,Thanks for your response i agree with you that turning of validation isnt a good solution. But at the moment it is the only solution the other party supports. The problem is we don't control the webservice versioning and therefore have no control over the service.