# How to implement new version of web services

Tags: java, web-services

I read this question for versioning web service:

[strategies-for-updating-or-versioning-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931109/strategies-for-updating-or-versioning-web-services)

and now I want to ask how to implement new version.

Now on the url: `myUrls/../v1` accepting web service. Now I want to create new version:  `myUrls/../v2`. I want to keep old web services and just add some new web services to new version. How should I do this ? I need to create new endpoint or I can use my current and just changed something.

thx for help

UPDATE:

I am using spring-ws and SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the change.  If you are just adding extra methods to a REST call then in theory, you can just add to your current service and all the other methods would still work.

If you are using a contract-first deployment such as SOAP, then you would need to versions as the WSDL would need to be updated.

It really depends on - do you want your service to be backward compatible for consumers on the current version?  If you are happy to force your consumers to refactor their code each time you make a change, then yes, just update the same URL endpoint each time, but if I was consuming your service this would annoy me somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are deploying your webservice.

Personally, if the change is backwards-compatible (as @david99world has pointed out) then you just add new operations into the existing service.

If the change is incompatible (i.e. interface of existing operations have changed), then I would package the new service as a new EAR/WAR.  That way you can run both services at the same time, so that not all of your service consumers need to change/test/deploy their code at the same time.  By having two separate versions, you can have a transition period where both services work (though that depends on for example whether underlying database changes would prevent `v1` from working at the same time as `v2`).

Also, if the change is unsuccessful, it is easy to just undeploy the `v2` WAR/EAR without affecting `v1` and by keeping the WAR/EARs separate you don't need to perform regression testing on `v1` just because you have introduced `v2`.

Because of using separate WAR/EARs, the URL strategy would most likely have to be `myURLv1/../v1` and `myURLv2/../v2`...

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yea but I dont want 2 war with same code = duplicity. Old client which are using url v1 should see new web serviced which are in version v2 so I need some idea how can I implement this

Comment: If you've got common code, then you can always move that into JARs used by both versions. I appreciate that two WARs might seem overkill but it is often a good thing that two different versions are in different wars as it is easy to prove to management-types that the new version doesn't use old code by mistake...